# linq query for update more than one record

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq

I have a table named `industries`. In this my fields are

- `workfor_id`,
- `workfor_usr_id`,
- `workfor_industry_id`.

With the same values of `workfor_id`, I have different `workfor_industry_id`'s.

```
foreach (var k in us){ 
    var ind = dbContext.industries.Where(i => i.workfor_id == 
        k.id).Select(i => i).FirstOrDefault(); 
    string ind2 = k.industry; 
    var industryParts =   ind2.Split(','); 
    var o = (industryParts.Length); 
    for (c = 0; c < o; c++){  
    ind.workfor_id = Convert.ToInt16(k.id); 
    ind.workfor_industry_id = Convert.ToInt16(k.industryid); }
     }
```

To update workfor_industry_id field I have implemented inner loop inside the foreach loop to get the values of workfor_industry_id's.here same record is over loading with  different workfor_industry_id's.

can you tell me how to implement this.

Comment: (1) Load the data from your context into a `List<industries>`, (2) iterate over the elements in that list and make your updates, (3) save that back to the database .....

Comment: Inside the iteration I have to iterate one more loop for getting workfor_industry_id.so the same record is overloading.

Comment: You're not being very clear on what you're trying to do. Can you please **update** your question and show us in code (even if it's pseudo-code) what you're trying to do and where you're stuck / unsure how to proceed?

Comment: foreach(var k in p){ var indList = dbContext.industries.Where(i => i.workfor_id == k.id).Select(i => i).ToArray();} with this i am getting multiple values with same workfor_id,but to update workfor_industry_id field I have to iterate one more loop,here the record is over loading

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: @steve, do you mean overlapping instead of overloading?

Comment: I have updated my question ,can u check it once

Comment: industry_parts contains id values separated by ",".It contains (workfor_industry_id's) like "1","2" like this.I have to update the records with these values only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED
This update adds a little more error checking and assumes that -1 is never a valid value for industry_id

```
short GetShort(string value) {
  short returnValue;
  value = (value ?? string.Empty).Replace("\"",null);
  return short.TryParse(value, out returnValue) ? returnValue : (short)-1;
}

foreach (var k in us){ 
  var id=Convert.ToInt16(k.id);
  var toRemove=from i in dbContext.industries
               where i.workfor_id == k.id
               select i;
  var toAdd = from x in (k.industry ?? string.Empty).Split(',')
              select new Industry { 
                      workfor_id=id,
                      workfor_industry_id=GetShort(x)
                    };

  dbContext.industries.DeleteAllOnSubmit(toRemove); 
  dbContext.industries.InsertAllOnSubmit(toAdd.Where(x=>x.workfor_industry_id != -1));

}
dbContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: similar to this,in the toRemove I am getting the exact records but in the toAdd I am not getting any records and it is saying that input string was not in correct format.in the k.industry I am getting values in "4,1" format.

Comment: @steve The error you are getting would indicate that x at the time of parsing is not a valid integer. What is the behaviour you want if each entry is not a valid integer?

Comment: actually workfor_industry_id is of type short.and I have made small change,at k.industry.Split(',') I am getting like "4,1" format

Comment: @steve Can you clarify is your k.industry `4,1` or is your k.industry `"4","1"`

Comment: the value is coming like "4","1"

Comment: it is showing the same.Input string was not in correct format,In the toAdd I am not getting any record

Comment: I can't see where the code would produce that error.  You have definitely used ALL the code I posted, including the extra function that uses short.TryParse?

Comment: In the GetShort method return statement it is showing error that cannot implicity conversion type "int" to "short"